# Xdebug for docker not connecting

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, xdebug-3

I am working on setting up Xdebug on Docker using this course- https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento

The site is up and running fine but Xdebug will not work. On the Chrome browser I have this setup-
[image]

It is enabled here-
[image]

Here are what my settings on PHPStorm look like-
[image]

Here is what the Run/Debug configuration looks like-
[image]

Here is all of my php information-
[image]

This is to show I did not forget the breakpoint-
[image]

What am I missing?

Edit:Xdebug Config
[image]

[image]

Edit: In Text Form-
xdebug

```
Version => 3.1.2
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: 
https://xdebug.org/support

         Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)             
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✘ disabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                        Optional Features                            
Compressed File Support => yes (gzip)
Clock Source => clock_gettime

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting 
renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => host.docker.internal => 
host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => no value => no value
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
 (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) 
=> (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in 
Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => 
cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting 
renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting 
renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting 
renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting 
renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => 
 (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
 xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
 xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 
3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => 
(setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.use_compression => 1 => 1
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

What it looks like when I try and validate-
[image]

Comment: Please show your xdebug config in config file

Comment: @themanhNguyen I added it.

Comment: Please share all text content in text form, not hidden in screenshots. Also, did you try to use "Break at first line"? Also, does PhpStorms validator help (it's hidden in the Run menu, at "Web Server Debug Validator")?

Comment: @NicoHaase I posted the text. I tried checking that line but it didn't do anything. As for the Web Server Debug what would I put in there? I am taking this course to learn how to set it up so I am not real experienced. Would this docker setup be considered a local web server or remote? I assume local since it is on the same computer. I can reach the site in my browser just fine. I have a screen shot of what it looks like when I try and validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on Linux/Ubuntu, it's possible the `host.docker.internal` host entry isn't set up on your local machine, which means Xdebug wouldn't be able to see Docker as a server to connect to.

This should be able to be resolved by adding an entry to your local machine's `/etc/hosts` file containing the value of your Docker network IP.

You can retrieve the Docker network IP by running:

```
docker network inspect bridge --format='{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'
```

Then, assuming that value is `172.17.0.1`, you can add the entry to `/etc/hosts` like so:

```
172.17.0.1 host.docker.internal
```

This binds the `host.docker.internal` hostname to your Docker daemon, so now Xdebug would be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't exactly say what is the problem, I suggest making these changes:

- Make sure the Run menu has this menu item: [image: Stop listening for PHP debug connections].
- Remove the `Filter debug connection by IDE key` configuration. The IDE key is somewhat useful if you have multiple websites that need to go to different environments, but I'm guessing that's not an issue for you.
- Enable `Break at first line in PHP scripts`.

There might be a couple of additional ideas in the troubleshooting [section here](https://matthewsetter.com/setup-step-debugging-php-xdebug3-docker/).

Comment: That item is in the Run menu. I unchecked the filter. I enabled break at first line in PHP scripts. One thing I find odd though is that it still says Waiting for incoming connection with ide key PHPStorm. Why would it still say that if I disabled that option?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is working with @Mark Shust docker and and his advise is not working for you, probably my experiense would be helpful.
The idea of checking `host.docker.internal` is a good one but in my case `docker network inspect bridge ...` shows me Gateway `172.17.0.1`as it was another network.

SO I had to find a right one:

after running `docker network ls` I received several networks.

Choosing a right one with name "m2test_default" and running `docker network inspect m2test_default` I received another Gateway `172.18.0.1` which is different than network in his `compose.yaml`.

Then I had to uncomment row and made changes in `extra_hosts` section in `compose.yaml` and change this network in `phpfpm` section as well.

Then I added this network to **/etc/hosts**

`172.18.0.1 host.docker.internal`

And it became working

**compose.yaml**

```
  ...  
  extra_hosts: &appextrahosts
      ## Selenium support, replace "magento.test" with URL of your site
      #- "magento.test:172.17.0.1"
      ## Linux, uncomment for Xdebug capabilities:
      - "host.docker.internal:172.18.0.1"

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:8.1-fpm-1
    volumes: *appvolumes
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:172.18.0.1"
  ...
```